# Yii: Avoid duplicating all properties from model in the form object

Tags: forms, model, yii

So I have a model like this:

```
class MyClass 
{
     public $customer = null;
     public $address = null;
}
```

And a form like this:

```
class MyForm extends CFormModel
{ 
     public $customer = null;
     public $address = null;

     /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     */
     public function rules()
     {
         return array(
         array('customer, address', 'required'),
         array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
     );

     /**
      * Declares customized attribute labels.
      * If not declared here, an attribute would have a label that is
      * the same as its name with the first letter in upper case.
     */
     public function attributeLabels()
     {
         return array(
               'verifyCode'=>'Verification Code',
         );
     }
}
```

What I would like to do, is extend the model in my form, but you can't do multiple object inheritance in PHP.

How would I do this, so as to avoid duplicating all of the field properties of model in form?

Comment: If you're thinking about crafting a custom form to retrieve values for various models, I recommend you to pass the view some blank models, and then retrieve each of them in the controller when submitted.

Comment: that would work if I extended CActiveRecord, but since I'm not, I'm missing all the validation code in my models.  Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: If 'MyClass' objects are going to stored in the db the right way would be to extend form CActiveRecord, if not, you can use directly the CFormModel object. I don't understand why you need a different class just to keep two properties. Could you detail more why you need the first class and cannot use only the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use of Component Behavior**

A component supports the [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) pattern and can be attached with one or several behaviors. A behavior is an object whose methods can be 'inherited' by its attached component through the means of collecting functionality instead of specialization (i.e., normal class inheritance). A component can be attached with several behaviors and thus achieve 'multiple inheritance'.

Behavior classes must implement the `IBehavior` interface. Most behaviors can extend from the `CBehavior` base class. If a behavior needs to be attached to a model, it may also extend from [CModelBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModelBehavior) or [CActiveRecordBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecordBehavior) which implements additional features specifc for models.

To use a behavior, it must be attached to a component first by calling the behavior's `attach()` method. Then we can call a behavior method via the component:

```
// $name uniquely identifies the behavior in the component
$component->attachBehavior($name,$behavior);
// test() is a method of $behavior
$component->test();
```

An attached behavior can be accessed like a normal property of the component. For example, if a behavior named tree is attached to a component, we can obtain the reference to this behavior object using:

```
$behavior=$component->tree;
// equivalent to the following:
// $behavior=$component->asa('tree');
```

A behavior can be temporarily disabled so that its methods are not available via the component. For example,

```
$component->disableBehavior($name);
// the following statement will throw an exception
$component->test();
$component->enableBehavior($name);
// it works now
$component->test();
```

It is possible that two behaviors attached to the same component have methods of the same name. In this case, the method of the first attached behavior will take precedence.

When used together with [events](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-event), behaviors are even more powerful. A behavior, when being attached to a component, can attach some of its methods to some events of the component. By doing so, the behavior gets a chance to observe or change the normal execution flow of the component.

A behavior's properties can also be accessed via the component it is attached to. The properties include both the public member variables and the properties defined via getters and/or setters of the behavior. For example, if a behavior has a property named xyz and the behavior is attached to a component $a. Then we can use the expression `$a->xyz` to access the behavior's property.

More reading:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events
http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2010/11/19/how-to-create-a-yii-behavior/